# pyspark read csv file with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read csv files from a directory with a particular pattern 
I want to match all the files with that contains this string `"logs_455DD_33`
t should match anything like "

> machine_**logs_455DD_33**.csv
>
> **logs_455DD_33**_2018.csv
>
> machine_**logs_455DD_33**_2018.csv

I've tried the following regex but it doesn't match files with the above format .

```
file = "hdfs://data/logs/{*}logs_455DD_33{*}.csv"
df = spark.read.csv(file)
```

Comment: Try this `file = "hdfs://data/logs/*logs_455DD_33*.csv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subprocess to liste files in hdfs and grep these files :

```
import subprocess

# Define path and pattern to match
dir_in = "data/logs"
your_pattern = "logs_455DD_33"

# Specify your subprocess
args = "hdfs dfs -ls "+dir_in+" | awk '{print $8}' | grep "+your_pattern
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# Get output and split it
s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
l_file = s_output.split('\n')

# Read files
for file in l_file :
    df = spark.read.csv(file)
```

Comment: Doesn't this specifically *not* use spark, which means that it will be slower across a cluster with a distributed file system? (HDFS/EMRFS)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar thing in my pyspark program where I need to pick a file in HDFS by cycle_date and I did like this:

`df=spark.read.parquet(pathtoFile + "*" + cycle_date + "*")`